# Calling main with sys.argv argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a main function which takes args from sys.argv using argparse:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-arg1', '--argument1', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-arg2', '--argument2', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

The main function is called from another module as mod.main().
When i print what is passed to the main function the args are: `['-arg1', 'val1', '-arg2', 'val2']` which is the correct list of arguments.

However, when i run it it seems that the args are not passed correctly with argparse.

```
['-arg1', 'val1', '-arg2', 'val2']
usage: -arg1 [-h] -arg2 ARG2 -arg1 ARG1
-arg1: error: the following arguments are required: -arg1
```

The issue is that i am not running the run_module.py which calls the module_to_call.main() from the command line but passing it as args to spark-submit in order to run it on EMR.

```
"HadoopJarStep": {
                "Args": [
                    "spark-submit",..., "run_module.py", "module_to_call", "-arg1", "val1", "-arg2", "val2",...
```

Comment: There cannot be anything passed to the main function because `main` does not take arguments. A proper `sys.argv` would have the program name at the first position, not `'-arg1'`. Where does the printed list come from and what is the [mre] for calling `main`?

Comment: The args are not passed directly but from the other module that calls main.
The module name is removed from sys.argv.
module_to_call =  sys.argv[1]
imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_to_call)
imported_module.main()

That module is called like run_module.py -arg1 val1 -arg2 -val2

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include that.

Comment: Basically the enveloping code has mangled your `sys.argv` and chewed away the first element. You can add a dummy element at the front of `sys.argv` to make sure that `-arg1` is safe. I have updated my answer below with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example for you

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# argparse_example.py
import sys
import argparse

def main():
    print(sys.argv)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-arg1', '--argument1', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-arg2', '--argument2', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can run it with

```
python argparse_example.py -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2
```

And get

```
['argparse_example.py', '-arg1', 'val1', '-arg2', 'val2']
Namespace(argument1='val1', argument2='val2')
```

Or run it without arguments

```
python argparse_example.py
```

to get the help message:

```
['argg.py']
usage: argg.py [-h] -arg1 ARGUMENT1 -arg2 ARGUMENT2
argg.py: error: the following arguments are required: -arg1/--argument1, -arg2/--argument2
```

**UPDATE**

From comments by the OP I realize that `sys.argv` got mangled on the way to function `main()` by some enveloping code and the first argument got cut off.

The argument list `['-arg1', 'val1', '-arg2', 'val2']` is **not** the correct list of arguments as it is missing `sys.argv[0]` — the name of the python script being called from the command line. As `argparse` processes `sys.argv[1:]`, it is unable to find `'-arg1'` and therefore fails with an error.

In this case you can add a dummy element to `sys.argv` to make sure that `-arg1` will be passed to `argparse` when your code is being run as a module.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# argparse_example.py
import sys
import argparse

def main():
    print(sys.argv)
    if __name__ != "__main__":
        # we are running as a module so add a dummy argument
        sys.argv = ['argparse_example.py'] + sys.argv
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-arg1', '--argument1', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-arg2', '--argument2', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can test it with the following enveloping code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# runner.py
import sys
import argparse_example

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]
    argparse_example.main()
```

And call it from the command line like this:

```bash
python runner.py -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2
```

The result should be the same as when calling `argparse_example` directly from the command line, even though `sys.argv` will be missing the first element:

```
['-arg1', 'val1', '-arg2', 'val2']
Namespace(argument1='val1', argument2='val2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the example. I have tried passing the module name but i am getting a different error this time: 
module_to_call.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2. 

I have tried adding it with a hardcoded value and with taking the module path with import.importlib(module_path) but it still cannot get the args correctly.